# Drop down menu (consisting of images) on image hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm starting a website ([Boys and Bunting](http://boysandbunting.blogspot.com)), and I have a horizontal navigation on top consisting of images next to each other.

I want the "shop" button to display a drop down menu. The drop down menu would ideally be 2 or 3 images NEXT to each other, which are links to other pages. So when someone clicks on SHOP, 3 images would come down next to each other that link to Patterns, Sewn Products, Crochet Products for example.

In my head it sounds quite easy, but I can't find what I need. I'm not a code writer, but I'm very good at reading and implementing them, or even adjusting them.

Comment: Here's an example of something I'm interested in. I've tried editing this to pieces to make it work for my website, but I feel like there's just too much code for what I need. http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/HorizontalSlideOutMenu/

Answer (score 0):

Why not starting from this [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) component "[DropDown Button](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns)" ?

Here is a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fb867Lje/) (editable).

For the external files, this will require :

- JQuery Includes (hosted online, [link is here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery))
- Bootstrap Include (hosted online, [links are here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn))

**Implementation**

Includes (within the `<head>` tag) :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If these are outdated, just keep including the latest of these (hope they will always be available online).

Core code (dropdown containing 3 photos with link to website) :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Shop
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <a href="stackoverflow.com">
            <img src="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg" width="40px" height="40px" />
        </a>
        <a href="stackoverflow.com">
            <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/964776/images/o-CATS-KILL-BILLIONS-facebook.jpg" width="40px" height="40px" />
        </a>
        <a href="stackoverflow.com">
          <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/mSFTRoBY99s/hqdefault.jpg" width="40px" height="40px" />
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the reply. I had a play around with it, but can't customise it enough. The drop down menu stays on the left side of the page, and is enclosed in a border with shadows around it. Thanks for your detailed reply though!